# Detect white pages with WIA

Tags: c#, wia

Exists a form "automatic" to detect white pages with WIA? Or i need create a method to do this. If I need do this I need convert to black and white, 1 bit per pixel?

Comment: It is hard to guess what you are talking about and what you want to achieve. Can you please add some words about your intention and what you´ve already done?

Comment: I want the best way to detect with pages when scanning file using WIA

Answer (score 2):

There`s no such thing in WIA (see reference below)
but you can use this method to check the returning picture:

http://www.chinhdo.com/20080910/detect-blank-images/

To use this function you don`t have to convert the picture.

---

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I try the code of Timex (existing in comments) but her's function always return that pages are white.

Comment: Works fine for me... is you image lower than 8 bit per pixel?
Try saving it as Jpg first and then scan it

Comment: The format of image is choosed by user. I work with bitmap from the image.

Comment: Thank you, not only do I love the fact that this function works, but with a little manipulation it works using a MemoryStream too!  Thank you!